SAS Reaching DataGrid Values
I have a DataGrid named mydatagrid. This DataGrid contains the following variables in order: AccountID, AccountType, and AccountGGS. Since a customer can have multiple account values, the number of rows in this DataGrid can vary. My goal is to access the AccountGGS values for all accounts of all customers and assign values to a variable based on certain conditions using these AccountGGS values.
Which DATAGRID function do I need to use (rule set)?

Please post a small example of the data you HAVE (ideally as a DATA step with a CARDS statement), and then describe the conditional logic you would like to use to calculate a new variable, and finally show the desired output data you WANT. As is, this question is too vague to answer.

SAS programming does not use the terms "DATATGRID" and "rule set."  Are you using a SAS "solution" such as SAS Intelligent Decisioning?  If so , please add the name of the product / solution you are using.  But for help with specific products, you may have more luck posting at communities.sas.com, since SO is focused on programming.

I am using SAS Intelligent Decision. As ı mentioned before, I have a datagrid which includes 3 different variable such as; AccountID, AccountType and AccountGGS. My output should be, a datagrid which includes AccountID, AccountType, AccountGGS, AccountBucket and LeadAccount. For example if AccountGGS = 0 then AccountBucket is 'B0', if 1 <= AccountGGS <= 30 then AccountBucket is 'B1',. But I do not know how can I do this.

This is best asked in SAS Communities: https://communities.sas.com/t5/Developers/bd-p/developers
